# How to disable or choose the 'correct' windows boot manager?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, bios, boot-manager

I have recently changed motherboard CPU and Ram, my PC was growing for around a decade and it's a bit of a mess. I have 4 Hard drives 1 SSD and 3 HDD all full of valuable data (not photos). Before changing motherboard I had 3 operating systems installed (2 x Win 7, 1 x XP). Windows boot manager was on HDD while Windows 7 installation that I was using was on SSD. When I changed hardware it failed to boot the system with `blue screen of death` and since I have changed 3 components it was real possibility of hardware failure. So to test I disconnected all HDDs and re-installed windows 7 on SSD (full format with partition deletion). After install I did hardware test it's all ok - so it was windows failing. I managed to connect 2 of HDDs back ok, but the one that had windows boot manager is now ruining my day. It offers me to `Recover windows` or `Start normally` choosing ether option results in couple of lines with `Windows loading files` and I end up in same screen of choosing same options. Even if I disable that HDD in BIOS as possible boot drive it still results in same. If I physically disconnect that HDD, SSD takes over and windows load up fine.
New motherboard is Asus Rampage IV Extreme, SSD drive is formatted as GPD. **Is there a way to set the hard drive configuration in such a way that HDD with boot manager would get ignored, or I would get an option of choosing which boot manager to use, or any other option to solve this that does not involve formatting HDD** as I just cant afford to lose the data on that HDD. If you need additional info I will do my best just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is obvious, putting the old drive on a new motherboard will most likely fail during boot since the motherboard drivers installed in windows will be for the wrong board, so what i suggest to do is to take your old HDD plugin it into a RAK attach it on the new motherboard via USB (it means you must boot with your new SSD) and copy your interesting files into another hard drive, then format this old HDD with the new motherboard, now you can attach your old HDD into your new motherboard and install a fresh version of Windows, and now you will have the boot menu to choose between different OS.

+1 if it helped, thank you.

Comment: Solution for £4.  http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/SATA-To-USB-2-0-Universal-Converter-Adapter-Cable-For-2-5-Hard-Disk-Drive-HDD-/390783268074?pt=UK_Computing_CablesConnectors_RL&hash=item5afc7f74ea

Comment: I'm not sure about the validity of what you said above, but getting a drive dock is not necessary. All he needs to do is boot Ubuntu (maybe even the Windows recovery environment if you want to try that) and copy the files from the "bad" drive to a different one. @LIUFA could even format the drive from Ubuntu using Gparted.

Comment: @MetaNova for the validity of my suggestion, am sure about it, i have been in problems like this, for your method yes it is valid, but i want something simple and obvious than something that needs more time and effort ...

Comment: It would probably take less time to download and burn/image write an ISO than buy something from eBay and wait for it to ship to you, but whatever. Also, all of this should be unnecessary as @LIUFA should be able to hit his"boot menu" key and select the good drive from the list.

Comment: in both methods you need to buy something in my case a cable that will save your life eternally and you could use it in any old HDD may be to copy files or to watch films in your TV, or your method you'll buy a CD or DVD to burn the iso ....

Comment: A USB stick would work fine too, and its hard to not having one of those laying around.

Answer (score 2):

You seem fairly confident in modifying BIOS settings, so if you haven't yet, try changing the boot order there. Make sure the bad drive is at the way bottom of the list.

Also, if, say the bad drive is using UEFI and the other is using MBR, many computers will prioritize UEFI over MBR so you may want to look into that also. When that is the case, there will often be more than one boot order list.

Worst case scenario is that you have to boot up a live Linux system to copy the files from the one drive to the other and format it from there.

Comment: Hello. BIOS offers option of using UEFI or legacy, and allows setting priority of one over other, I have already tried but this didn't help, to my understanding if boot manager is used then it's UEFI by definition as boot manager is part of it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#UEFI_booting so I would think that both of hard drives have managers that both rely on UEFI. It was a logical suggestion though - I have an option to re-install windows using MBR on SSD and the give priority to legacy, thanks.

Comment: It depends how you define "boot manager". There are two main ways of booting: The legacy way, which involves reading boot code off a special area of the hard disk called the MBR (that then usually loads more code off somewhere else on the disk), and UEFI, which involves loading boot code off a FAT partition on the disk. Windows can use either method to boot.